# How to re_enter same activity when home pressed?

Tags: android, android-activity

My app has 3 activities on the stack A->B->C

If you press home and after 1 hour re-enter the application, another instance of A 
is started, so the stack is A->B->C.

What I want is that when the user re-enters the app, they re-enter on 
the same activity they were in before.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is normal bcoz, if your app is killed by Android for memory, it starts from the first, if not it will be started from the activity where you left it

Comment: how do u have 4 activities if u have only A,B and C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this attribute to the manifest entry for your **root activity** (ie: Activity A in your example):

```
android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Android automatically kills (destroys) the Activities to save memory, but the functionallity you ask for could maybe be achieved by saving a flag for wich activity is shown last in the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). Then you can just run a check every time Activity A is started and if B is the one to be shown, just start B. (onCreate that is) Just be careful when switching between A, B and C.